# W Small Cap + dot kerning

Tags: xetex, kerning

How can I change the kerning of specific small caps, specifically `w` and `v` in combination with dot and comma?

With XeTeX, I found out how to change upper and lowercases, but no luck with small caps unicode number, at least with `Fanwood Text`, `Junicode` or `EB Garamond`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\fooV
\newXeTeXintercharclass\foov
\newXeTeXintercharclass\fooDot
\XeTeXcharclass "56=\fooV % Capital V
\XeTeXcharclass "76=\foov % Lowercase V
\XeTeXcharclass "F776=\foov % Small Cap v in Junicode
\XeTeXcharclass "2C=\fooDot % Comma
\XeTeXcharclass "2E=\fooDot % Dot
\XeTeXinterchartoks\fooV\fooDot{\kern-.12em}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\foov\fooDot{\kern-.06em}

\begin{document}
    EV,
    ev,
    \textsc{ev},
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the comma within the scope of the command which switches the font. Kerning has no meaning between fonts and small-caps is essentially a different font as far as TeX is concerned. (I'm not sure quite how this goes for the newer engines, though.)

[image: adjusted kerning]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\fooV
\newXeTeXintercharclass\foov
\newXeTeXintercharclass\fooDot
\XeTeXcharclass "56=\fooV % Capital V
\XeTeXcharclass "76=\foov % Lowercase V
\XeTeXcharclass "F776=\foov % Small Cap v in Junicode
\XeTeXcharclass "2C=\fooDot % Comma
\XeTeXcharclass "2E=\fooDot % Dot
\XeTeXinterchartoks\fooV\fooDot{\kern-.12em}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\foov\fooDot{\kern-.06em}

\begin{document}
  EV,
  ev,
  \textsc{ev},
  \textsc{ev,}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It makes sense... but now I realize that it's going to be a huge problem, because I wanted to modify this kerning pair for a biblatex shorthand I'm using a lot on a document. The output is something like `MEW, 8, p. 107.` MEW stands for Marx-Engels Werke.

Comment: @Ludenticus I think you should post a new question in that case as it is going to raise different issues. You can link to this one as part of that question.